# returning an Observable or a number from a function and how to test it

Tags: typescript

I have a function which should either return an `Observable` or `-1` if the argument is incorrect.

```
public getX(x:...): Observable|number {
    switch(x) {
      case 3:
        return Observable..
        break;
      default:
        return -1;

    }
}
```

What is the way to check that the function call returned an `Observable` or `-1`?

```
y = getX(..)

if(y === -1) //would this work if `getX` actually returns an `Observable`?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if check will always work correctly, since an Observable will never equal to -1. Alternatively you could just return undefined or null and do a simple `if (y)` since undefined or null are falsy.

Also, you don't need a break statement after a return function in your switch case.

Comment: Thanks Tom. The break statement is just to ensure that if I change the logic and remove return in future, I don't miss the break.